# Cannot resolve package dependencies following LTS upgrade from Lucid to Precise

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, apt, dpkg

After a failed LTS upgrade from **Lucid** to **Precise**, I'm stuck in package limbo.  As root I have run

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```

Outputs appended below.

The default package archive at this point contains packages for **Precise**.
What should I do to get past this?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
In response to:   dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-vmware:
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware depends on libxatracker1; however:
  Package libxatracker1 is not installed.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-intel:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on libxcb-dri2-0; however:
  Package libxcb-dri2-0 is not installed.
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on libxcb-util0 (>= 0.3.8); however:
  Package libxcb-util0 is not installed.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware
 xserver-xorg-video-intel

In response to:   apt-get -f install

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gvfs-bin: Depends: gvfs (= 1.6.1-0ubuntu1build1) but 1.12.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
  gvfs-fuse: Depends: libgvfscommon0 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not installable
         Depends: gvfs (= 1.6.1-0ubuntu1build1) but 1.12.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
  initramfs-tools: Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (= 0.92bubuntu78) but 0.99ubuntu13 is installed
  libglib2.0-0-dbg: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.24.1-0ubuntu1) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
  libglib2.0-dev: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.24.1-0ubuntu1) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
  libnih1: Depends: libc6 (< 2.12) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
  plymouth: Depends: libdrm-nouveau1 (>= 2.4.11-1ubuntu1~) but it is not installable
  python-louis: Depends: liblouis0 (>= 1.7.0-2) but it is not installable
  xserver-xorg-video-all: Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nv but it is not installable
                      Depends: xserver-xorg-video-v4l but it is not installable
  xserver-xorg-video-intel: Depends: libxcb-dri2-0 but it is not installed
                        Depends: libxcb-util0 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not installed
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware: Depends: libxatracker1 but it is not installed

------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Kept fussing with it.

Comment: Decided to use dpkg -i on the .debs in /var/cache/apt/archive for libxatracker1, libxcb-dri2-0, and libxcb-util0.  This succeeded.

Comment: Then "apt-get update" (which did find new things), "dkpg --configure -a", and "apt-get -f install" broke the log jam.  So I could get then get quite a bit farther with "apt-get dist-upgrade", to the point where the system booted normally apart from bringing up X11 and some form of desktop.  New issue to follow.

Comment: BTW, there were dependency issues with gvfs to work around.

Comment: You should probably add your solution as answer, so that other see this is solved and can try it if they have the same problem.

Comment: Also try to use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` when possible. It's a little smarter. As a general rule of thumb, whenever a package manager says « _package_ is not installed », « _package_ is not going to be installed », etc., the first thing to do is to try to install _package_ manually. A lot of times this is sufficient to go on with installation.

Answer (score 3):

why not try

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

dpkg --configure -a

apt-get -f install package name here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into a similar problem and none of the solutions have worked to resolve this so far.

```
    apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  bsdmainutils: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  g++: Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.2.3-1ubuntu6) but it is not installed
  gcc: Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5) but it is not installed
       Depends: gcc-4.6 (>= 4.6.3-1~) but it is not installed
  gedit: Depends: python2.5 (>= 2.5) but it is not installable
         Depends: python-gtksourceview2 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installed
         Recommends: python-gnome2 but it is not installed
  gimp: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  gnome-about: Depends: python-gnome2 but it is not installed
  gnome-app-install: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: python-gconf but it is not installed
                     Depends: python-launchpad-integration but it is not installed
                     Depends: python-sexy but it is not installable
  gnome-games: Depends: python-gnome2 but it is not installed
               Depends: python-gnome2-desktop (>= 2.17.3) but it is not installable
  gnome-orca: Depends: python-pyatspi
              Depends: python-gnome2 (>= 2.6.2) but it is not installed
              Depends: python-gnome2-desktop but it is not installable
  gnome-panel: Depends: gnome-control-center (>= 1:2.8.2-3) but it is not installed
               Recommends: alacarte but it is not installed
  gnome-session: Depends: gnome-control-center (>= 1:2.22) but it is not installed
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf: Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1) but 2.24.10-0ubuntu6 is installed
  hal-cups-utils: Depends: python-usb but it is not installed
                  Recommends: hplip but it is not installed
  ifupdown: Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but 2.86.ds1-59ubuntu13 is installed
  initramfs-tools: Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.99ubuntu13.5) but it is not installed
                   Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.5.1~) but it is not installed
  jockey-common: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  language-support-writing-en: Depends: hunspell-en-us but it is not installed
  libattr1-dev: Depends: libattr1 (= 1:2.4.46-3) but 1:2.4.46-5ubuntu1 is installed
  libc-dev-bin: Depends: libc6 (< 2.12)
                Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not installed
  libc6: Conflicts: libc6-i686
  libc6-dev: Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.13 is installed
             Breaks: binutils (< 2.20.1-1) but 2.18.93.20081009-0ubuntu1 is installed
             Breaks: gcc-4.4-base (< 4.4.6-3ubuntu1) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is installed
             Breaks: make (< 3.81-8.1) but 3.81-5 is installed
             Breaks: pkg-config (< 0.26-1) but 0.22-1 is installed
  libc6-i686: PreDepends: libc6 (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.13)
  libgail18: Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1) but 2.24.10-0ubuntu6 is installed
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0: Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (= 2.26.1-1) but it is not installed
                      Breaks: libgtk2.0-bin (< 2.21.3) but 2.14.4-0ubuntu1 is installed
                      Breaks: librsvg2-2 (< 2.26.3-2) but 2.26.3-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
                      Breaks: libwmf0.2-7 (< 0.2.8.4-7) but 0.2.8.4-6ubuntu0.8.10.1 is installed
  libglib2.0-0: Depends: libpcre3 (>= 8.10) but 7.8-3build1 is installed
                Breaks: gnome-session (< 3.0.0-3) but 2.24.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
                Breaks: gvfs (< 1.8) but 1.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
  libgtk2.0-0: Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.28.3) but 1.22.2-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
               Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.1.5-2ubuntu1.1 is installed
  libidl0: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  libnih1: Depends: libc6 (< 2.12)
  libpython2.6: Depends: python2.6 (= 2.6.5-1ubuntu6.3) but it is not installable
  libssl-dev: Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not installed
              Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not installed
  libssl1.0.0: Breaks: openssh-client (< 1:5.9p1-4) but 1:5.1p1-3ubuntu1 is installed
  nautilus: Depends: gnome-control-center (>= 2.6) but it is not installed
  onboard: Depends: python-gconf but it is not installed
           Depends: python-virtkey (>= 0.50) but it is not installed
  openoffice.org-emailmerge: Depends: python-uno but it is not installed
  python-apport: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
                 Depends: python-problem-report (>= 0.94) but it is not installed
  python-beagle: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-brlapi: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-cairo: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-cups: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-cupshelpers: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-dbus: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-gdbm: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-gi: Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.31.0) but 1.30.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-gmenu: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-gst0.10: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-gtkhtml2: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-launchpad-bugs: Depends: python2.5 but it is not installable
  python-libxml2: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python-minimal: Breaks: python-support (< 1.0.10ubuntu2) but 1.0.4ubuntu1 is installed
  python-notify: Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is installed
  python2.7: Depends: libdb5.1 but it is not installed
  rhythmbox: Depends: python2.5 (>= 2.5) but it is not installable
             Depends: python-gnome2 (>= 2.18) but it is not installed
             Recommends: yelp but it is not installed
  system-config-printer-gnome: Depends: python-gnome2 but it is not installed
  totem: Depends: totem-gstreamer (>= 2.24.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable or
                  totem-xine (>= 2.24.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
  totem-mozilla: Depends: totem-gstreamer (>= 2.24.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable or
                          totem-xine (>= 2.24.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
  totem-plugins: Depends: totem-gstreamer (= 2.24.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable or
                          totem-xine (= 2.24.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-rdflib but it is not installed
  ubuntu-docs: Depends: gnome-user-guide but it is not installed
               Depends: yelp but it is not installed
  upstart: Depends: mountall but it is not installed
  upstart-logd: Depends: upstart (= 0.3.9-8) but 1.5-0ubuntu5 is installed
  x11-apps: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  x11-session-utils: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  x11-utils: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  x11-xkb-utils: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  x11-xserver-utils: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  xinit: Depends: cpp but it is not installed
  xulrunner-1.9: Depends: python2.5 (>= 2.5) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```